# 2S-1D vs 2S-2D vs Polyphase file sorting

Tags: file, sorting, time-complexity, file-sorting

Can someone explain me the comparisons of which one is better and their time and space complexity and anything important that you think that is worth knowing. I know how 2S1D and 2S2D work.

Comment: Hope you don't mind this comment asking about your deleted question [If we denormalise a database to 2NF, what precaution should we take while writing queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106823/if-we-denormalise-a-database-to-2nf-what-precaution-should-we-take-while-writin): What did your prof want as an answer & what exactly was their question & what did they mean by it? Were they by my standards assuming misconceptions & fuzziness re querying? (Your question would likely have been better received if it had been clearer & if you had shown some attempts to research & answer it.)

Comment: @philipxy Question: If I denormalise a database (let's say from 3nf to 2nf) what precautions should I be taking?
Ans; Using Stored procedures, assertions, triggers.
What do you think about this?

Comment: As I said those are only relevant to *erroneous update requests*. (Recall that I asked whether "queries" included updates--it doesn't normally--& if so "Read re why we constrain & normalize & re anomalies.") We should enforce that the projections of the denormalized relation that correspond to the more-normalized originals join back to it. Thanks.

Comment: PS Typo in my comments on that question: "*(higher NF)*" should have been "*(lower NF)*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that "S" means source and "D" means destination, so you're comparing 2 source 1 destination versus 2 source 2 destination, and ordinary merge sort with polyphase merge sort. The wiki article includes these cases:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyphase_merge_sort

Note that the wiki article is focused on external sorts, where compare overhead is ignored and only movement of data is considered.

For an internal ordinary merge sort, with random access memory, a 2S-2D sort only requires two arrays, as the 2 sources can be even and odd runs within a single source array, and the output can also be to a single array. For an internal polyphase merge sort, you need at least 3 arrays (2S-1D). On my system, even though 3 array polyphase merge sort does about 5% more moves than 2 array ordinary merge sort, polyphase ends up about 5% faster, probably due to cache issues.

Trivia - for a 3 stack (LIFO only interface version of 2S-1D), polyphase merge sort is fastest.